# Python in-place complement operator

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

Python has the usual bitwise operators, like `~`, `&`, `|`, etc. and in-place operators like `+=`, `&=`, etc. to simplify expressions like:

```
a = a & 34234
a = a + 577
```

To:

```
a &= 34234
a += 577
```

Despite the complement operator `~` being an unary function, and not following the same structure because it isn't used with two values (like `a` and `34234`), can expressions like these be simplified with another type of operator?

```
a = ~a # not bad at all

# Still easy to code but seems redundant
self.container.longVariableName.longName = ~self.container.longVariableName.longName
```

Comment: Use shorter variable names. If using it twice is too cumbersome, I find it hard to imagine that using it once would be any better.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus this is a bit of a made-up issue, I know. The real question to me is about a possible ~=-like operation.  And sometimes shorter variable names aren't favourable over ones that are easily understood, depending on the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's excruciatingly obscure, but:

```
self.container.longVariableName.longName ^= -1
```

does the job, so long as the values you're dealing with are integers.  "Are integers" is required so that there's an exploitable mathematical relation between the `~` and `^` operators.

Why it works:

1. Bitwise complement is the same as xor'ing with an infinite string of 1 bits.
2. Python maintains the illusion that integers use an infinite-width 2's-complement representation, so that -1 "is" an infinite string of 1 bits.

Comment: Interesting.  I suppose a bit more knowledge on bitwise operations would have let me find this myself.  Then it's a tradeoff since I'd probably need to write a small comment beside it to clarify for others reading the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only concerned about doing this for attributes of object instances, you could write a method like:

```
def c(obj, atr):
    setattr(obj,atr,~getattr(obj,atr))
```

and then use it like:

```
c(self.container.longVariableName, 'longName')
```

I think that @TimPeters answer is much better, but thought I'd provide this in case it is useful to anyone in the future who needs to do this with non-integers are is happy to only work with instant attributes